# "Bad system call" error while working with shared memory

Tags: c, cygwin, ipc, shared-memory

I'm new to shared memory and ive come up with the following code:

```
int main()
{
  int perm=S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO;
  int fd=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,1024,IPC_CREAT|perm);
  if(fd<0)
  {
    printf("error");
    _exit(0);
  }
  int* sum=(int*)shmat(fd,0,0);
  if(*sum==1)
  {
    printf("error\n");  
    _exit(0);
  }
  *sum=0;
  printf("asjjsad=%d",*sum);
  return 0;
}
```

When i run this i get *bad system call*.

Whats wrong?

I'm trying to assign sum to 0 and the have a child process compute a value, say sum1. Then i have to try to add sum1 to sum.

How do you do this?

Comment: I compile and run your code without any error, the result is correct.

Comment: Which line gives you "*bad system call*"?

Comment: it just says bad system call.

Comment: Who is "*it*"? Which platform are you on? Did you try to run the app using a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the OP's issue occurs on Cygwin, the following paragraph from Cygwin's [Implementation Notes](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/std-notes.html) helps:

> The XSI IPC functions semctl, semget, semop, shmat, shmctl, shmdt, shmget, msgctl, msgget, msgrcv and msgsnd are only available when cygserver is running.